# Work Permit with Student Residence Permit in Iceland

Tags: resident-permit, student-visa, study, iceland

I intend to move to Iceland for my graduate studies. Iceland, however does not issue work permits with student visas (student residence permits). My university site says that a part time work permit has to be obtained through the prospective employer.

The official website of Immigration in Iceland says that you need to apply beforehand and that it is not possible to apply once you come into the country without leaving and reapplying. Can someone clarify the correct way to obtain a work permit with my student residence permit in Iceland?

This is important to me as I intend to finance myself through my studies by working part time.

Comment: There appears to be a separate form that allows [application for a work permit as a student](http://www.utl.is/files/Leyfi/atv_Vegna_nams.pdf) and which is sent to Immigration. In that context, it suggests you do not have to leave the country. Have you contacted your school or the [Directorate of Immigration?](http://www.utl.is/index.php/en/school)

Comment: Please take a look at [this document](http://en.ru.is/media/althjodaskrifstofa/skjol/Student-Visa-Handbook-Non-EU.pdf) from Reykjavik University. You need to have at least 6 months of living expenses to get a student visa. While U is in session, no more than 15 hrs per week of work for which you need to get a permit.

Comment: Helpful. I found out this too. Seems I will have to go there and then apply ``If you want to work in Iceland, you will need a work permit. You will also need a contract of
employment from the company that agrees to hire you. After you have found a job, have them
fill out the contract form. Then, fill out the blue form from immigration. Go to the immigration
department and submit these two forms. Then wait for the labor board to approve or deny your
work permit, and they will send you a response in the mail. ``

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Iceland Directorate of Immigration](https://www.utl.is/index.php/en/), you would need to make [application for a work permit as a student](http://www.utl.is/files/Leyfi/atv_Vegna_nams.pdf) and which is sent to Immigration. In that context, it suggests you do not have to leave the country. At the same time, you should coordinate this request with the international student office at your school.